# Use Output of Android MediaProjection API as Source for libjingle WebRTC Library?

Tags: android, webrtc, libjingle, android-mediaprojection

I am trying to create an Android app that utilizes the [libjingle WebRTC native Android library](http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/android) to project the users Android desktop to a peer using WebRTC. To that end, I have successfully used the [pristine.io libjingle mirror](https://github.com/pristineio/webrtc-mirror) to recreate the [Android apprtc example](https://github.com/pristineio/webrtc-mirror/tree/master/webrtc/examples/androidapp) application using:

```
compile 'io.pristine:libjingle:10531@aar'
```

in my apps build.gradle file. The apprtc example woks fine with the https://apprtc.appspot.com/ demo web site. I have also created a separate app that records the user's screen to an H.264 encoded mp4 file using the `MediaProjection` library introduced in Android API 21 following the example posted [here](http://www.truiton.com/2015/05/capture-record-android-screen-using-mediaprojection-apis/).

Now, I would like to marry these two ideas into an app that utilizes the raw stream from `MediaProjection` and `MediaRecorder`, or at least the H.264 encoded file, as the video/audio stream for the WebRTC peerconnection. Is this even possible? The `PeerConnection.addStream` method in libjingle expects an instance of `MediaStream`. How can you create an object of type `MediaStream` from the raw stream or from the resulting mp4 file?

Thank you for any insight you might be able to provide!

Comment: also i have the same problem. did you solve this problem? can you guide me for solve this problem? thanks